# How do I solve Eric 6 Python IDE PyQt5 not found Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, eric-ide

The error is:

[image: eric error console]

Eric 6 does not work at all with Python 3.4.2 & PyQt5. I've made installation in the sequence: Python-->PyQt-->Eric 6, but the console shows error as above, why?

How can this error be solve?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the command pip install pyqt5 for starters.

Hopefully you have qt5 installed first.

Comment: No you can't. PyQt5 isn't installable via pip

Comment: Apparently it's possible now: pip3 install PyQt5.  However, if you're doing it this way, Eric6 doesn't "see" it's installed and keeps on complaining.  Still looking why it's like that...

Answer (score 0):

I just solve the problem yesterday.
my ENV as follow:

1. python 3.5.2
2. Eric 6-18.06
3. PyQt5-10.1

after i installed python3.5 success,and with command "pip install pyqt5".
i used "pip install QScintilla" command befor i install Eric6!
then,the problem happended as yours.
It turns out to be wrong, you should use "python install.py" to install Eric6 first after you installed pyqt5!

To solve the problem,you can try "pip uninstall QScintilla",and "python install.py" to install Eric6.Then it will be prompt QScintilla dependencied ,enter "y" .The Eric6 will be installed successfully.hope this helps.